Flutter: TextField: how to define a custom doubleTap handler preserving the default word selection behavior?
I want to call my custom function onDoubleClick on a double tap in a TextField still preserving the default behaviour of the double tapped word to get selected.
TextField does not provide an onDoubleTap attribute, so I wrapped it into a GestureDetector like so:
GestureDetector(
  onDoubleTap: () {
    if (widget.onDoubleClick != null) {
      widget.onDoubleClick!(_textEditingController.value);
    }
  },
  child: TextField(
     controller: _textEditingController,
  ),
)

This makes my function onDoubleClick successfully execute onDoubleTap but the default behavior of the double tapped word to get selected is unfortunately eliminated. Trying using all kinds of HitTestBehavior for the GestureDetector attribute behavior does not change a thing.
I probably could go the way not to wrap with GestureDetector and to use the second call of the onTap handler, but then I would need to use an own value for the time interval between the first and the second tap. I do not want to do that because this value is an OS-level user setting that I do not want to deviate from.
So, how do I get my custom function onDoubleClick called on a double tap in a TextField still preserving the default behavior of the double tapped word to get selected?

Try to set flag to identify like below:
bool _isEditing = false;

on iniState set
_textEditingController.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    _isEditing = true;
  });
});

And your gestureDetector like below...
GestureDetector(
      onDoubleTap: () {
        if (_isEditing) {
          print('Custom double tap');
        } else {
          final TextSelection textSelection = _textEditingController.selection;
          final String text = _textEditingController.text;
          int start = textSelection.baseOffset;
          int end = textSelection.extentOffset;
          while (start > 0 && !text[start - 1].contains(RegExp(r'\s'))) {
            start--;
          }
          while (end < text.length - 1 && !text[end].contains(RegExp(r'\s'))) {
            end++;
          }
          _textEditingController.selection = TextSelection(
            baseOffset: start,
            extentOffset: end,
          );
        }
      },
      child: TextField(
        controller: _textEditingController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Type something...',
        ),
      ),
    );


Unfortunately, that does not work as requested, and I do not understand how that is supposed to work: after the initial addListener _isEditing remains true for ever and 'Custom double tap' is printed every time. Even if I fix that, there is either a selection made or custom branch is executed but never both. Even if I unite both branches, the proposed solution is just a manual implementation of a word selection. But I'd rather like to preserve the Flutter/system given behavior.
